# Schedule software updates on mac Big Sur at a particular time

Tags: macos, mac, software-update

I am very new to use mac and sorry for asking this kind of basic question.

I want to schedule my mac's software update to happen after midnight. Is there anyway to schedule that?

- macOS Big Sur
- version 11.2.3 (20D91)